# How can skip match with Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can skip match with Regex i wanna to get `ss` and skip `=`

Code:

```
var patt = new RegExp("=ss","g");
var url = "https://mass.lass.com/?t=ss";
var x = url.match(patt);
console.log(x);

//result
=ss

i only need SS
```

Comment: Try something like ```var patt = new RegExp("=(ss)","i");```

Comment: Or just use built in methods `const val = new URL("https://mass.lass.com/?t=ss").searchParams.get("t")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind. Instead of

```
new RegExp("=ss","g")
```

you can use

```
new RegExp("(?<==)ss", "g")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function (more generic), it takes params and url as a parameters

```js
 

const url = "https://mass.lass.com/?t=ss";

const getQueryParams = ( url, params ) => {
  let reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + params + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
  let queryString = reg.exec(url);
  return queryString ? queryString[1] : null;
};

console.log(getQueryParams(url, "t"))
```